# Is it normal to create indexes on the fly?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Is it a normal practice to create indexes on the fly in MongoDB using ensureIndex.

Or I need to create index in advance and then not to call ensureIndex each time I request db?

Comment: The idea behind an index is to pre-compute some stuff so at query time you can find what you are looking for more quickly at query time. If you re-index for every query it kind of defeats the purpose. However, mongoDB will only create an index on the field if it doesn't already exist. I would make sure to have a really good reason before doing this.

Answer (score 0):

EnsureIndex is deprecated (see [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/)). [Creating an index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/) is expensive computationally and will block database activities while the process completes. You can run builds in the background but the load may still impact system performance. One a replica set you can remove each cluster member individually and build the index in standalone mode to ensure that index builds do not impact overall cluster performance.

So build your indexes offline once and remember that indexes are not for free and will impose a write fan out as each index requires an additional write operation when you insert or update.